# tlmgr stopped working with error message 'Unknown tag'

Tags: texlive, updating

I tried today to update my install, and tlmgr does not want to cooperate:

```
$ tlmgr update --all
Unknown tag: runfiles si at /work/usr/texlive/2010/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 241, <TMP> line 105460
```

What can the problem be? How can I fix this?

Comment: try `tlmgr update --self --all`

Comment: @Herbert, I did, but it gives the same error

Comment: @Peter: then drop a line to he texlive mailing list

Comment: @Herbert Isn't this the place to answer this? I don't like mailing lists. Maybe some of the people there will read it here also.

Comment: @Peter: yes, it is!

Comment: @Peter: This kind of errors are better in the hands of the developer. Because it is hard to reproduce this issues such questions are under the risk to be closed as "too localized". On the other hand if the question is answerable, it is nice to have both Q&A around because Google results favor stackexchange sites, so people with the same issue will find a solution quickly.

Comment: @Peter: You might want accept Tomek's answer instead of mine. It seems to be the (more) correct one.

Comment: @Peter in addition to accepting Tomek's answer, you should check back to award the bounty (which has to be done separately.)

Comment: @Alan I know :) I wait with that until the last day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please, **do not** replace `texlive.tlpdb` from your installation with `texlive.tlpdb.be17af42b38bde18ed074dc333c8326e` or any such file!   This file is a cached copy of the package database from the remote repository, kept to speed up network operations (it is downloaded only if it changes).  The long hexadecimal number is a hash of the repository location, from which this file came.  Your local `texlive.tlpdb` is not the same as the one from the repository and should not be replaced by it.  Instead, you can regenerate it by calling (the output goes to stdout):

```
tlmgr recreate-tlpdb > texlive.tlpdb
```

Comment: Ah, good to know. I just assumed it was a backup file. It has almost the same as size than the original.

Comment: Thanks Tomek! I executed this command, and after that a tlmgr update, and it seems it reinstalled quite some packages. Now I think everything is working!

Answer (score 1):

I had a look on this now. The error message seems to be caused by a defect `texlive.tlpdb` data base file, most likely caused by an interrupted download. The `runfiles si` should actually be `runfiles size=<number>`. You need to replace this file with a good one.

It is normally located in the `tlpkg` directory of your TeXLive installation, which is `/usr/local/texlive/2010/tlpkg` for me, but seems to be `/work/usr/texlive/2010/tlpkg` for you.
<strike>Look into this directory, there should be a backup file named like `texlive.tlpdb.be17af42b38bde18ed074dc333c8326e` (the last part is a random hexadecimal number and will be most likely different for you). Copy that file over the `texlive.tlpdb` file and try it again.</strike>

If this doesn't work download the DB file manually, e.g. from http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb, and replace the existing file. This should fix your problem.

Comment: I had to download the DB file manually, but after that it seems to work all again! Thanks!

Comment: I checked, it seemed to work, but it didn't. Somehow it actually didn't update any packages.

Comment: @Peter: Ok, sorry for that. I looked like the right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway! You were right about the part that the corrupted tlpdb file was the problem!